# Correct way to model many to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am modeling a database for a personal project and I have the following doubt.
what is the difference in modeling my database between the following options?:

**A option**

[image]

**B option**

[image]

The difference between option **A** and **B** lies in the way of modeling the contract table, in the **A option** the *PK* of contract is composed for all attributes, but in **B option** the *PK* of contract is only the attribute id_contract, but contract have two forean keys that can not be null.

My goal with this design is allow multiple contracts between users and providers, the above can be achieved with **A option** or **B option** but, If I think of the functional dependencies, I need *Id_user*, *Id_Provider* and a *numerical sequence* to identify a **contract**. The problem is that if the *numerical sequence* is autoincrementable, it becomes a surrogate key. Leaving aside all the theory of database design, but if this is not self-increasing, it becomes an indispensable part of the identity of the entity (*Id_user*, *Id_Provider* and a *numerical sequence*).

My question is oriented to know what are the possible implications of choosing to model **A** or **B** thinking of a good design of the database.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a unique surrogate key `id_Contract` anyway, there is no reason to include other fields into `Contract`'s primary key: a single primary key is sufficient. Option "B" also makes your intentions easier to see by programmers looking at your database design.

In general, you would not include a separate surrogate key attribute in a composite primary key. A big advantage of a composite key is an ability to go without a surrogate key for the table. Since both designs allow multiple contracts among users and providers, you don't have a clean option of avoiding a surrogate key.

Comment: my goal with this design is allow multiple contracts between users and providers. if I think of the functional dependencies, I need Id_user, Id_Provider and a numerical sequence to identify a contract. But if it turns out that if the sequence is a autoincrement, the other keys do not need to identify a contract, this is where my doubt lies, which means that I do not find a difference between option A and B that I mention

Comment: @AlejoDev Your autoincrement field is a surrogate key. Once you have that, there is no reason to add other fields to PK, because they do not provide any help in identifying the contract,

Comment: thanks for your answers, I agree with what you say, but then the only difference between A and B is only how I want to identify the table. Do not you think there should be more implications if I take design a or b?

Answer (score 0):

This set of indexes

```
PRIMARY KEY(contract_id)
INDEX(user_id, provider_id, contract_id),
INDEX(provider_id, user_id, contract_id)
```

Provides:

- The rest of what `AUTO_INCREMENT` needs, namely `contract_id` to be the *first* column in *some* index.
- Efficient way to get from a user to all his providers and vice versa (a la a many-to-many table).

This would also work:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, provider_id, contract_id),
INDEX(provider_id, user_id, contract_id)
INDEX(contract_id)
```

Notes:

- It does not enforce `UNIQUEness` of `contract_id`, but that should not be an issue if you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the normal way (never `INSERTing` an explicit value).
- It provides links starting with each column.

I don't know how to correctly draw the model.  At some point, the schema must be implemented, and *that* becomes the source-of-truth about how the schema works.

The way InnoDB is implemented, either triple of indexes becomes 3 BTrees, each of which contains all the columns, but arranged in different ways.  That is, `SELECTs` should find either triple identical for performance.  `INSERTs` will insert at the 'end' of the BTree for contract_id and insert in various places for the other two BTrees.  Again, no diff in performance.

More on many-to-many tables [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).